# How to install Timescaledb-toolkit extension on Windows server

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

Does timescaledb support Timescaledb-toolkit extension on Windows server?
Unable to find any doc to install timescaledb-toolkit extension on windows server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Toolkit doesn't support Windows currently, and probably won't gain Windows support in the near future.

See also [this discussion](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/discussions/447).